# hive json regular expression

Tags: regex, json, hadoop, hive

I have a json structure like this :

```
{
    "filings": {
        "All Reports": {},
        "Statement Of Income Alternative": {
              lieItem1 : [],
              lineItem2 : []    
         },
        "Statement Of Financial Position Classified (Parenthetical)": {},
        "Statement Of Financial Position Classified": {},
        "Statement Of Shareholders Equity And Other Comprehensive Income": {},
        "Entity Information": {},
        "Statement Of Cash Flows Indirect": {},
        "Document Information": {},
        "Notes to Financial Statements": {}
    }
}
```

I am doing a query on this struture in hive using get_json_object :

```
  get_json_object(table.json,'$.filings.Statement Of Income Alternative.lineItem1')
```

the exact value of the term `Statement Of Income Alternative` is not known in advance, so is it possible to use regular expression on this, i tried this :

```
 get_json_object(table.json,'$.filings.* Income Alternative*.lineItem1')
```

return empty results. If this structure doesnt allow me to do this any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any control of what the json contains? The easy way would be to have a field that contains the exact name of "Statement of Income Alternative".

Comment: lineItem[] contain a json object so i can add this value there and then use it in where condition but that will be lot of repetition of same value :  "Statement of Income Alternative"

Comment: Well truth be told, your json keys are quite complicated and I'm not sure you really need that. The whole point of designing the json yourself is to be sure of the structure it will have (and not have the name of the keys change like that). Perhaps you could find a generic name that always applies?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo :  the json shows lieItem1 but your expression is using lineItem1